# django filters.py @property def qs user

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter, django-filters

I am trying to filter the associated_portfolios fields object to only those created by the user. Which worked before I tried to add pagination (which is working if I remove the current filter I have for associated_portfolios)

I believe what I need to do is remove:

```
def associated_portfolios
```

this is because it seems request is not past with the new setup. Instead, I should use this method https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs

**filters.py** current; not working after adding pagination

```
def associated_portfolios(request):
    associated_portfolios = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return associated_portfolios.all()

class TradeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    associated_portfolios = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=associated_portfolios)
    date_range = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(label='Date Range', field_name='last_entry',
                                                      widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = ['status', 'type', 'asset', 'symbol', 'broker', 'patterns', 'associated_portfolios']
```

**filters.py** possible solution based on documentation

```
class TradeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_range = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(label='Date Range', field_name='last_entry',
                                                      widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = ['status', 'type', 'asset', 'symbol', 'broker', 'patterns', 'associated_portfolios']

    @property
    def qs(self):
        parent = super().qs
        user = getattr(self.request, 'user', None)
        return parent.filter(user=user)
```

The problem is the is no error message but the objects not created by the user are still showing. Tried probably a dozen + variations of this @property from what I've seen on SOF and the docs but no success yet..

**views.py**

```
class FilteredListView(ListView):
    filterset_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Get the queryset however you usually would.  For example:
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        # Then use the query parameters and the queryset to
        # instantiate a filterset and save it as an attribute
        # on the view instance for later.
        self.filterset = self.filterset_class(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        # Return the filtered queryset
        return self.filterset.qs.distinct() #.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('last_entry')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Pass the filterset to the template - it provides the form.
        context['filterset'] = self.filterset_class
        return context

# Attempt @ Combining Filter and List View to get: TradeFilteredListView
class TradeFilteredListView(FilteredListView):
    model = Trade
    filterset_class = TradeFilter
    paginate_by =  5
    template_name = 'portfolios/trade_filter.html'
```

**Side notes:**

1. The reason I am using a different view setup is due to pagination which I followed this guide on for setting up pagination with django-filters. https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/10/18/filtering-and-pagination-django/